# Conversion of string into JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to send data from my android app to a server but when I am trying to run my app, it connects with the server, but after a while an error stops my app.

the error is:

> "05-04 19:39:36.401: E/JSON Parser(2323): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value abc@yahoo.com of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

In the below code .... please check the last `try-catch`....
If anyone has any ideas, please help ...

```
public class JSONParser {static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: could you post what you're getting from the server? The current code doesn't looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are trying to convert the string "abc@yahoo.com" to JSONObject. You'll need the String to be in JSON Format. Something like :

```
{
    "email":"abc@yahoo.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading a simple string value, such as an email, let's say **abc@yahoo.com**, then you should first create the JSONObject, and set the key/value pair in it.

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
    **jObj = new JSONObject();**
    **jObj.putString("email", json);**

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
```

*Answer edited with part of the original code*
Now, you have created your own JSONObject in case the server doesn't returns one.
Hope it helps.

Comment: List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",signupusernameString));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", signupemailString));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",signuppasswordString));

// Note that create product url accepts POST method
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_signup,
      "POST", params);

using this I pass email...

Comment: I'm referring to the response you get from the server. If it's something like **abc@yahoo.com**, it should be **{"my_key":"abc@yahoo.com"}** so it becomes a JSONObject. See the edited answer where I reuse the section when you should read the stream and modify it.